# Match surrounding text around a group match

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Here is an example:

```
<li><a href="link" target="_parent">1. Tips and tricks</a></li>
```

regex:

```
/tips(?![^<]*>)/ig
```

Matches the word Tips.

What I want to do is to be able to match the surrounding text too, possibly in another group?

So the match could be `e.g. ["1. Tips and tricks", "Tips"].`

You can test it out [here](http://www.regexr.com/394ie)

Comment: Why don't you use an HTML parser rather than regular expressions?

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? All the text between the `<a>` tags?

Comment: I am trying to find the text nodes only and I found using regex is much easier than traversing the DOM. The reason being is that I am translating the language of text, therefore I only need the text info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to get this,

```
>>> import re
>>> str = '<li><a href="link" target="_parent">1. Tips and tricks</a></li>'
>>> m = re.findall(r'((?<=>)\d+\.\s*(Tips)[^<]*)', str)
>>> m
[('1. Tips and tricks', 'Tips')]
```

**OR**

```
>>> str = """
... <li>
... <a href="link" target="_parent">
... 1. Tips and tricks
... </a>
... </li>"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'\s*<a[^>]*>\n(\s*\S*\s*(\S*)[^\n]*)', str)
>>> m
[('1. Tips and tricks', 'Tips')]
```

Comment: I am using re.finditer and it does not seem to be returning any results for the first solution.

Comment: The second solution does not work well, because some html tags are still left.

Comment: could you post the actual input in pastebin?

Comment: It was just an example. It should be able to match anythig inbetween > and <

Answer (score 1):

Following your comment, I think that it is way simpler to use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and then use `re.split` to clean up a bit:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """<li class="selected ">
<a href="http://localhost:8888/translate_url" target="_parent">
          Learn the Basics: get iniciared
        </a>
<ul class="subtopics">
<li>
<a href="http://localhost:8888/translate_url" target="_parent">
                Tips and tricks
                </a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://localhost:8888/translate_url" target="_parent">
                Use bookmarks
                </a>
</li>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
text = re.split(r'\s{2,}', soup.get_text().strip())
```

Output:

```
['Learn the Basics: get iniciared', 'Tips and tricks', 'Use bookmarks']
```

---

`soup.get_text()` gets all the text in the page. Then use `strip()` to remove leading and trailing spaces so you don't get empty strings in your list of text.

Answer (score 0):

The Python documentation for the `re` module states that:

> Subgroups are numbered from left to right, from 1 upward. Groups can be nested; to determine the number, just count the opening parenthesis characters, going from left to right.

So, for example, the following (ugly) pattern would match the surrounding text in one group and the target word from your example link:

```
/[^\n\s](.*basics(?![^<]*>).*)\n/ig
```

You can refine this for your case!

Edit: *It is still a pretty bad idea to use regular expressions for parsing HTML, something like `beautifulsoup` would be more robust.*

Comment: I am trying to find the text nodes only and I found using regex is much easier than traversing the DOM. The reason being is that I am translating the language of text, therefore I only need the text info. I have used beautifulsoup, but I have found it to be more work compared to what regex does easily.